# How to Communicate with Azure Service Bus Programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I am an automation test engineer using Selenium C#.  However, part of my testing is in processing a package on the Azure Service Bus.  I am not familiar with that.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Azure Service Bus API for c#.

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

A full tutorial for using it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).